# Django get all post of a parent category

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm a begginner in django 3 and i decide to create a simple blog to pratice what i learned .

I created a post model with a foreignkey category , and a model category with a self foreign key . Everething work well and i find a way to create my menu , the problem is when i click on the parent i want to have all post for the submenu .

For example , I have this menu :

*Informatic
   * Django
   * HTML - CSS

*Graphic

If i'm clicking on django , i have all my django post , same for html-css but now i want to have all informatic post , posts who have django + html-css together .

I can modify my model Post and instead to have a field with category in foreign key , i could use a manytomanyfield . But i don't want it , because i can forgot to put in informatic or in other category . 
So what could I do, in a simple way ?

Can you explain to me what and how todo , and where i need to put code

I'm not sure what code do you need , but there :

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    menu = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='subcategory')

    def children(self):
        """Return replies of a comment."""
        return Category.objects.filter(parent=self, menu=1)

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        """Return `True` if instance is a parent."""
        if self.parent is not None:
            return False
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        """Return results of instance with no parent (not a reply)."""
        qs = super().filter(parent=None)
        return qs
```

And my version of post without the other fields

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=1)
```

And in my menu template :

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories%}
    {% if not category.parent %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'category-post' cslug=category.slug%}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% for subcategory in category.children %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'category-post' cslug=subcategory.slug %}">--- {{ subcategory.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And the view

```
def category_post(request, cslug ):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cslug)
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=cslug)
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'posts': posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/category_post.html', context)
```

If you need more precision please tell me :)

Comment: a reverse query will list all the posts related, `subcategory.post_set.all()`

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

add a related_name par in Foriegnkey in Post model 
REF:[DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

you will be able to call posts from category with related name ... so if you make `relate_name='posts'` that mean you will access posts from category like that `category.posts.all()` or `category.posts.filter()` or `category.posts.all()[slice]`

Comment: First thank you for your answer ,I already have a relate_name="subcategory" . So I try with the shell to write category.subcategory.all() but it's write:QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subcategory' . It's note working , did i do something wrong ?

Comment: Oh and it i put an uppercase for Category , 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Answer (score 0):

I was so tired i didn't even notice i create a def in my model and i use it with yours answers and now it's working . Thank you both of you